# How to read structure field values from writecallback in open62541

Tags: c, variables, callback, opc-ua, open62541

Currently, I'm working on read and write callback in open62541, I created a structure variable XV type, It's fields are X and V in XML file

X is a type of double and V is a type of float

if I write the value using the client tool it's entering into the write callback function and I'm able to print the X value alone using the print `cout<<"Field value is "<< *(double*)data->value.data<<endl;`, but I'm unable to fetch the second value that is V,

I took the below code as a reference, in that in the **afterWriteTime callback** function I tried

`cout<<"Field value is "<< *(double*)data->value.data<<endl;`this print statemet

it's printing only the X's value alone, how can I get two values from the callback function

```
#include <open62541/plugin/log_stdout.h>
#include <open62541/server.h>
#include <open62541/server_config_default.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void
updateCurrentTime(UA_Server *server) {
    UA_DateTime now = UA_DateTime_now();
    UA_Variant value;
    UA_Variant_setScalar(&value, &now, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DATETIME]);
    UA_NodeId currentNodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "current-time-value-callback");
    UA_Server_writeValue(server, currentNodeId, value);
}

static void
addCurrentTimeVariable(UA_Server *server) {
    UA_DateTime now = 0;
    UA_VariableAttributes attr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
    attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "Current time - value callback");
    attr.accessLevel = UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_READ | UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_WRITE;
    UA_Variant_setScalar(&attr.value, &now, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DATETIME]);

    UA_NodeId currentNodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "current-time-value-callback");
    UA_QualifiedName currentName = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(1, "current-time-value-callback");
    UA_NodeId parentNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_OBJECTSFOLDER);
    UA_NodeId parentReferenceNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_ORGANIZES);
    UA_NodeId variableTypeNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_BASEDATAVARIABLETYPE);
    UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, currentNodeId, parentNodeId,
                              parentReferenceNodeId, currentName,
                              variableTypeNodeId, attr, NULL, NULL);

    updateCurrentTime(server);
}

/**
 * Variable Value Callback
 * ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 *
 * When a value changes continuously, such as the system time, updating the
 * value in a tight loop would take up a lot of resources. Value callbacks allow
 * to synchronize a variable value with an external representation. They attach
 * callbacks to the variable that are executed before every read and after every
 * write operation. */

static void
beforeReadTime(UA_Server *server,
               const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
               const UA_NodeId *nodeid, void *nodeContext,
               const UA_NumericRange *range, const UA_DataValue *data) {
    updateCurrentTime(server);
}

static void
afterWriteTime(UA_Server *server,
               const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
               const UA_NodeId *nodeId, void *nodeContext,
               const UA_NumericRange *range, const UA_DataValue *data) {
    UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_USERLAND,
                "The variable was updated");
      cout<<"Field value is "<< *(double*)data->value.data<<endl;
}

static void
addValueCallbackToCurrentTimeVariable(UA_Server *server) {
    UA_NodeId currentNodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "current-time-value-callback");
    UA_ValueCallback callback ;
    callback.onRead = beforeReadTime;
    callback.onWrite = afterWriteTime;
    UA_Server_setVariableNode_valueCallback(server, currentNodeId, callback);
}

/**
 * Variable Data Sources
 * ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 *
 * With value callbacks, the value is still stored in the variable node.
 * So-called data sources go one step further. The server redirects every read
 * and write request to a callback function. Upon reading, the callback provides
 * a copy of the current value. Internally, the data source needs to implement
 * its own memory management. */

static UA_StatusCode
readCurrentTime(UA_Server *server,
                const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
                const UA_NodeId *nodeId, void *nodeContext,
                UA_Boolean sourceTimeStamp, const UA_NumericRange *range,
                UA_DataValue *dataValue) {
    UA_DateTime now = UA_DateTime_now();
    UA_Variant_setScalarCopy(&dataValue->value, &now,
                             &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DATETIME]);
    dataValue->hasValue = true;
    return UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD;
}

static UA_StatusCode
writeCurrentTime(UA_Server *server,
                 const UA_NodeId *sessionId, void *sessionContext,
                 const UA_NodeId *nodeId, void *nodeContext,
                 const UA_NumericRange *range, const UA_DataValue *data) {
    UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_USERLAND,
                "Changing the system time is not implemented");
    return UA_STATUSCODE_BADINTERNALERROR;
}

static void
addCurrentTimeDataSourceVariable(UA_Server *server) {
    UA_VariableAttributes attr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
    attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "Current time - data source");
    attr.accessLevel = UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_READ | UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_WRITE;

    UA_NodeId currentNodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "current-time-datasource");
    UA_QualifiedName currentName = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(1, "current-time-datasource");
    UA_NodeId parentNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_OBJECTSFOLDER);
    UA_NodeId parentReferenceNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_ORGANIZES);
    UA_NodeId variableTypeNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_BASEDATAVARIABLETYPE);

    UA_DataSource timeDataSource;
    timeDataSource.read = readCurrentTime;
    timeDataSource.write = writeCurrentTime;
    UA_Server_addDataSourceVariableNode(server, currentNodeId, parentNodeId,
                                        parentReferenceNodeId, currentName,
                                        variableTypeNodeId, attr,
                                        timeDataSource, NULL, NULL);
}

static UA_DataValue *externalValue;

static void
addCurrentTimeExternalDataSource(UA_Server *server) {
    UA_NodeId currentNodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "current-time-external-source");

    UA_ValueBackend valueBackend;
    valueBackend.backendType = UA_VALUEBACKENDTYPE_EXTERNAL;
    valueBackend.backend.external.value = &externalValue;

    UA_Server_setVariableNode_valueBackend(server, currentNodeId, valueBackend);
}

/** It follows the main server code, making use of the above definitions. */

static volatile UA_Boolean running = true;
static void stopHandler(int sign) {
    UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER, "received ctrl-c");
    running = false;
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, stopHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, stopHandler);

    UA_Server *server = UA_Server_new();
    UA_ServerConfig_setDefault(UA_Server_getConfig(server));

    addCurrentTimeVariable(server);
    addValueCallbackToCurrentTimeVariable(server);
    addCurrentTimeDataSourceVariable(server);

    addCurrentTimeExternalDataSource(server);

    UA_StatusCode retval = UA_Server_run(server, &running);

    UA_Server_delete(server);
    return retval == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
Footer
© 2022 GitHub, Inc.
Footer navigation
Terms
Privacy
Security
Status
Docs
Contact GitHub
Pricing
API
Training
Blog
About
open62541/tutorial_server_datasource.c at master · open62541/open62541 · GitHub
```